# Pyqtgraph: Overloaded AxisItem only showing original data

Tags: pyqt, python-3.6, pyqtgraph

I'm building an application to view real time data based on the examples for scrolling plots. My x-axis should display time as a formated string. The x-values added to the plot are timestamp floats in seconds. Here is a simplified version of my plot window code.

Everything works in real time and I have no problem showing the values i want to plot, but the labels for my x-axis are only the timestamps not the formated strings. I know that the function formatTimestampToString(val) in the AxisItem overload returns a good string value.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg


class NewLegend(pg.LegendItem):
    def __init__(self, size=None, offset=None):
        pg.LegendItem.__init__(self, size, offset)

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen(0,0,0)) # outline
        p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush(255,255,255)) # background
        p.drawRect(self.boundingRect())


class DateAxis(pg.AxisItem):
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        strings = []
        for val in values:
             strings.append(formatTimestampToString(val))
        return strings


class PlotWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, iof, num):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Plot Window ')
        self.resize(1000, 800)

        pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
        pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')

        """
        ... other stuff ...
        """

        # Externally updated dict with data
        self.data = {}

        self.curves = {}

        self.plotWidget = pg.GraphicsWindow("Graph Window")

        axis = DateAxis(orientation='bottom')
        self.plot = self.plotWidget.addPlot(axisItem={'bottom': axis})
        self.plot.setAutoPan(x=True)
        self.legend = NewLegend(size=(100, 60), offset=(70, 30))
        self.legend.setParentItem(self.plot.graphicsItem())

    def updatePlots(self):
        #update data for the different curves
        for data_name, curve in self.curves.items():
            if curve != 0:
                curve.setData(y=self.data[data_name].values[:], x=self.data[data_name].timestamps[:])

    def addCurve(self, data_name):
        if data_name not in self.curves:
                self.curves[data_name] = self.plot.plot(y=self.data[data_name].values[:], x=self.data[data_name].timestamps[:], pen=pg.mkPen(color=self.randomColor(),width=3))
                self.legend.addItem(self.curves[data_name], name=data_name)

    def removeCurve(self, data_name):
        if data_name in self.curves:
            self.plot.removeItem(self.curves[data_name])
            self.legend.removeItem(data_name)
            del self.curves[data_name]
```

Am i doing something wrong? Is there a better way to overload the AxisItem? I have also tried to overload the AxisItem with a simple numerical formula just to see if it has any effect on my axis.

Another problem i have is with the LegendItem: I can add and subtract labels with no problem, but it only updates the size of the legend box when adding labels. This means that when I add and remove curves/data in my plot the legend grows, but never shrinks down again. I have tried calling the LegendItem.updateSize() function after removing labels, but nothing happens.

I hope you can help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem. In `self.plot = self.plotWidget.addPlot(axisItem={'bottom': axis})` its supposed to say axisItems, not axisItem.